# Can we decide the width of field based on character array size from database?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on a jasper report in which I have to display number of fields next to each other. Now I am getting confused about deciding the width of fields. I thought to look into the size of fields in the database tables and then specify the size of fields in iReport designer.

But I can't do like this. Because if size of a field from database is 20 characters and if I specify width of a field in iReport as 20 then it's too small for 20 characters.

I can execute the reports and adjust the size of fields based on the output but right now I don't have data in some tables. So report won't get populated to verify.

So is there any optional way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you want to **dynamically increase the width of the text field**.

If this is your case, then I am sorry to say that, you ***cannot*** dynamically increase the **width** of a component in jasper reports. But you can dynamically increase the **height** of the text field.

To increase the **height of the component dynamically**, enable property "**Stretch with overflow**".

Comment: Yeah... I tried this option and it was increasing height of the field.

Comment: That is what I have mentioned in the answer. You cannot increase the width dynamically in jasper reports.